# How to config the webView background-color with the web body background color

Tags: html, ios, webview, background

I know that we can use the following codes to config a webView background color:

```
self.webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.webView.opaque=NO;
```

but I'm confused that how to get the background color of a web and set **THE COLOR** to the webView background.
We can use 'document.title' to get the title of a web, is there anything similar to 'document.title'*(maybe 'document.background color' , i don't know)* to get the background color of the HTML(WEB)?Thanks!

Comment: you can get the background color, as like `UIColor* buttonColor = self.webView.backgroundColor`

Comment: @ Anbu.Karthik   I mean I only know the URL of the webPage, such as 'www.google.com', and I want to config the webView background color of the app with the page background color.